# styling my bootstrap modal with CSS

Tags: css

I am trying the Move records Modal exactly on top of below Modal but I am not getting the styling that I need. Below is the image and I am applying styling on it.
Here is my image link

:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwgG2ftgvg_YUnZNRnpaWmFIZkNYbEg2WVZuLXBuZEtkNEo0

Comment: what's the matter do you want us to style your modal or do you need help where you stock styling it

Comment: I need help in styling . i have tried adding z-index in bootstrap.min.js but i am not getting where to add this z-index attribute

Comment: give it on the `.modal` class

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the greater z-index for container which should be in front than container on back.

Comment: I need help in styling . i have tried adding z-index in bootstrap.min.js but i am not getting where to add this z-index attribute